# Бесплатный хостинг и сайт на Битрикс

Tags: битрикс, интернет-магазин, веб-сайт

Доброго времени суток.
Я совсем новичок в этом и вообще мало представляю как это должно работать .
Моя задача развернуть тестовый интернетмагазин на бесплатном хостинге на платформе битрикса.
Я посмотрел хостинги, там глаза разбегаются, но везде какие-то свои ограничения и я не знаю в какие я могу упереться, или же для тестового сайта ( на мой сайт не должны заходить люди, кроме меня самого или кого-то, кого я попрошу посмотреть ) не имеют значения эти ограничения? Может посоветуете хостинг какой?
Также как сайт поставить на платформу битрикса
Видел, что у битрикса есть готовые демосайты, но так как я не пробовал я не знаю как это всё должно работать.
Собственно мне нужно найти подходящий хостинг, и понять как поставить на него сайт на битриксе, может кто направит на верный путь? И есть ли разница для хостинга или ещё чего, что ставить, так как мне нужен именно сайт-магазин.
Всё в целях обучения и ознакомления с битриксом, по этому буду крайне благодарен за любую информацию.

Comment: Тестовый сайт можно запустить на своём домашнем компьютере, хостинг для этого не требуется

Comment: бесплатные предложения от хостингов не дадут развернуть цмс - оптимальный вариант - пилить на своем компе (битрикс дает демо-лицензию на месяц)

Comment: Возможно, но неужели нельзя никак поставить демосайт на хостинг, чтобы он более-менее адекватно работал? Мне нужно  поставить его, иметь возможность загружать парсер товара из екселя просто. Хочу все обновления делать через гит, чтобы было как в рабочей версии.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В свое время тестировал на виртуалке. Help на сайте Битрикса очень хороший.
https://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/learning/course/index.php?COURSE_ID=37&LESSON_ID=8811
А демо-лицензию можно продлять.
Самое главное - грамотно развернуть CentOS.
Или скачать готовую виртуалку https://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/learning/course/index.php?COURSE_ID=37&CHAPTER_ID=08809&LESSON_PATH=3908.8809

Comment: Какая принципиальная разница при запуске с виртуалки или с хостинга? С точки зрения работы с сайтом.

Comment: Никакой разницы нет. Разворачиваете виртуалку на своем localhost. Даете доступ к виртуальной машине по сети и сами становитесь виртуальным хостером. Показываете потенциальному заказчику результаты. Все зависит от ваших знаний по безопасности  CentOS, Apache, nginx

Comment: Ну еще вразумительного домена не будет.